# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' in Laravel

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel-5

I have a function where i insert recort to db.But when i execute this function, i get the message **SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'**

[Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GDjN.png)

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfgo8.png)

My function in controller

```
public function postCheckout(Request $request){
    if(!Session::has('cart')){
        return view('cart.shopping_cart');
    }
    $data = $request->all();
    $oldCart=Session::get('cart');
    $cart=new Cart($oldCart);       
    $order=new Order();
    $order->order_code="Order00006";
    $order->user_id=Auth::user()?Auth::user()->id:1;
    $order->full_name=$data['full_name'];   
    $order->phone=$data['phone'];
    $order->address=$data['address'];
    $order->recieve_address=$data['recieve_address'];
    $order->total_product=$cart->totalQuantity;
    $order->total_price=$cart->totalPrice;      
    $orderArr=array($order);
    Order::insert($orderArr);
}
```

In model

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $table="orders";
    protected $fillable = [
    'order_code','user_id','full_name','phone', 'address', 'recieve_address', 'total_product','total_price' ,
    ];
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Save function instead of insert

```
public function postCheckout(Request $request){
if(!Session::has('cart')){
    return view('cart.shopping_cart');
}
$data = $request->all();
$oldCart=Session::get('cart');    
$order=new Order();
$order->order_code="Order00006";
$order->user_id=Auth::user()?Auth::user()->id:1;
$order->full_name=$data['full_name'];   
$order->phone=$data['phone'];
$order->address=$data['address'];
$order->recieve_address=$data['recieve_address'];
$order->total_product=$oldCart->totalQuantity;
$order->total_price=$oldCart->totalPrice;      
$order->save();
echo "Data saved"; die;
}
```

Comment: So,if i want to saving multi record to database, how can i excute with save method ?

Comment: yes @john exactly insert will also work but you to read the documentation of laravel 5.2

Comment: glad to help :)